# C++ how to handle class types when writing a scripting language

Tags: c++

I've been stumped by this for some time although I believe it may be quite simple. I am writing a simple programming language in c++ and I can't figure out the best way to handle variable types withing my language.

For example I may have eight different variable types including string, number, bool, table, etc! I need to know the best way to store these within c++ because they are all different types, which means all different classes! I will have many more than eight types though. The code is line based with a compiler. Please help!

Comment: I just need a simple answer, nothing complicated unless it's necessary.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is off-topic here. For more info: [help]. This might be better placed at [programmers.se].

Comment: There are no simple answers here. Only complicated ones.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to use a technique some call "type boxing".  PHP for example uses something along these lines (more C-ish):

```
enum class ScriptVarType {
    STRING,
    NUMBER,
};

struct ScriptVar {
    ScriptVarType type;
    union {
        std::string str;
        int num;
    };
};
```

You can also used derived classes if all your types are classes.  They can share a `ScriptVar` base class, and you can use RTTI (or similar) to obtain the actual type, such as `ScriptVarString`.

User definable types just need to have members to define all the user parts.

Comment: please avoid use union in C++, use `boost::variant` instead.